# How do I step through the go build process?

Tags: go, debugging

For learning purposes, I would like to step through go's build process or, in other words, what happens when you run `go build main.go`.

I trivially attempted to use delve on the go entry point at `go\src\cmd\go\main.go` by running `dlv debug -- build C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\GoTest\main.go` and immediately got:

```
ambiguous import: found package cmd/go in multiple directories:
        C:\Program Files\Go\src\cmd\go
        C:\<where i cloned the repo>\go\src\cmd\go
exit status 1
```

I am on windows 10.

Comment: `go build -x main.go`

Comment: `go help build` may give some more insight. Found in the official documentation: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program . I don't really know what "step through" means though.

Comment: @Peter This just prints the name of the temporary work directory for me

Comment: @Gimby https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepping_(debugging) the go command doesn't help with this since it doesn't have debug capabilities

Comment: If -x doesn't print anything then your build is probably up-to-date, so there's nothing to do.

Comment: @Peter okay, I can see what it's packaging now, but I would prefer to use delve to step through the execution line-by-line